# Convert date in DynamoDB from unix format using PartiQL

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, unix-timestamp, partiql

I am trying to select data from DynamoDB using the PartiQL new AWS feature. I have noticed that the date variable is stored in Unix format in Dynamodb. However, I want to convert it into human readable format such as GMT.

I have used the next expression but it does not work, it gave me an error

```
SELECT num_id, Date(last_activity_time)
FROM "cc-our-table"
```

Is there any other solution how to convert it into gmt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately PartiQL doesn't provide the ability to cast values.

Comment: so there is no possibility to convert unix timestamp into gmt in Partiql?

Comment: Correct. You can see its full functionality here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html

Comment: @LeeHannigan, should be possible using `DATE_ADD`, no?